# Apache Flink: When is a function on a window called?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When is a windowed transformation function invoked by Flink? Is it invoked once at window end boundary or invoked upon receiving each message?

Comment: For the `countWindow`, it is invoked on the arrival on the message which makes the number of accumulated elements in the window equals the `count`(Actually it is done by `CountTrigger`). But for `timeWindow`, it is done by the internal timer in Flink.

Answer (score 2):

[ReduceFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#reducefunction)s and [AggregateFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction)s are called as each element is added to the window, and [ProcessWindowFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#processwindowfunction)s are called when the [Trigger](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers) fires.

Answer (score 0):

The window Trigger is responsible for this.

In detail: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers